# Python script requires permission to copy files

Tags: python, python-2.6, shutil, os.system

I am trying to write a python script to copy some files from one place to another like this:

`os.system('cp file/path/a file/path/b')`

when I run this within the python prompt it works just fine. But if I put this in a python script it fails with the error

`cp: cannot create regular file 'file/path/b': Permission denied`

I am getting this error even when I run the script using sudo permissions i.e. `sudo ./mysript.py`

So what is going on here and is it possible for me to fix this?

EDIT 1:

Following the suggestions of @kungphu and @ShadowRanger I switched from using `os.system` to using `shutil.copy`. The problem persists however I am now getting a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./myscript.py", line 21, in <module>
    shutil.copy('/absolute/file/path/a', '/absolute/file/path/b')
  File "/python/lib/python2.6/shutil.py", line 84, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/python/lib/python2.6/shutil.py", line 50, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/absolute/file/path/a'
```

Comment: It's usually better to use Python's built-in facilities for things it supports. Rather than calling out to the OS manually, you might want to try [`shutil.copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) and see if you get more consistent behavior. Also, it may help to make sure you're using full paths rather than relative ones.

Comment: Does `file/path` exist in the working directory (*not* the script directory, unless you're running it while `cd`-ed into the same directory as the script? Try adding `print(os.path.getcwd())`, and seeing if it's what you think it is, and whether `file/path` exists under it (and is a directory). Are the source and destination directories actually the same, and if not, does the destination directory already exist (`cp` won't create it for you normally)? Beyond that, seconding @kungphu, use `shutil`; `os.system` is a stability (and in some cases, security) risk, with terrible error reporting.

Comment: I have changed my copy to use `shutil.copy` and I also checked that my cwd is correct. I then went ahead and prepended my cwd to the src and dest paths and have verified that both paths exist previously so there shouldn't be any issues with that. After switching to using `shutil.copy` I am now getting a permissions error on the src file rather than the dest.  So I went and looked at the permissions for that file and it is `rw-r--r--` so there shouldn't be any problem with permissions even without sudo.

Comment: If you just run on your own command from the command line `cp file/path/a file/path/b` does it work?  Just making sure you _really_ do have the right paths as opposed to something with python

Comment: @sniperd, Interestingly enough when I try using `shutil.copy` in a python prompt it complains that the filepath doesn't exist. However I have verified that the path does actually exist. The source dir `file` in my example is actually a mount location so maybe python doesn't recognize any path within there?

Comment: @sniprd, Sorry I am realizing I had tried this on a different machine (both are connected by nfs) but the `file` directory wasn't populated with the mount contents on that machine. So I retried it on the same machine I did the mount on and it does work without any errors